# How update a matplotlib chart in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I wanna update a embedded chart in a Tkinter GUI with a button and I am not really sure how to do this, right now the closest solution to this that i found is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import *

# Creation of the mainwindow and container frame
root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
mainframe.tkraise()

# Embed the chart to the Tkinter Window
fig1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(8, 3), dpi=100)
plot1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, mainframe)
chart1.get_tk_widget().place(x=300, y=10)


# Button section
def plot_graph():
    A = [2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
    fig1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(8, 3), dpi=100)
    plot1 = fig1.add_subplot(111).plot(A)
    chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, mainframe)
    chart1.get_tk_widget().place(x=300, y=10)


plot_btn = Button(mainframe, text='Plot graph', command=plot_graph)
plot_btn.grid(row=0,column=0)
# Mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

The problem with this is that when i press the plot button a new graph is created and inserted over the previous one and i dont want to do that, i just want to update the first one that i created. I am pretty new with Tkinter, any idea of how i can do this?

Comment: If i am right , you want it to be a live graph ?

Comment: Yes, i am working on a GUI for plotting some functions, in the real project code i have some entries for the generation of the functions, like frecuency, amplitude, etc. And i just want to plot that function in the graph when i click the plot button. So the graph may update every time i generate a different function, i want to clear the previous function plot and plot the new one everytime i hit the button